# How can I write data attributes using Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I feel like I am missing something. When I try to use a `data` `attribute` in my `template`, like this:

```
<ol class="viewer-nav">
    <li *ngFor="#section of sections" data-sectionvalue="{{ section.value }}">
        {{ section.text }}
    </li>
</ol>
```

`Angular 2` crashes with:

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'sectionvalue' since
> it isn't a known native property ("
>
> ]data-sectionvalue="{{ section.value }}">{{ section.text }}

I'm obviously missing something with the syntax, please help.

Answer (score 654, accepted):

Use attribute binding syntax instead

```
<ol class="viewer-nav"><li *ngFor="let section of sections" 
    [attr.data-sectionvalue]="section.value">{{ section.text }}</li>  
</ol>
```

or

```
<ol class="viewer-nav"><li *ngFor="let section of sections" 
    attr.data-sectionvalue="{{section.value}}">{{ section.text }}</li>  
</ol>
```

#### See also :

- [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2/36745752#36745752)

Comment: how do i access the value of the data attribute?

Comment: Please create a new question with some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: This should be Googles #1 answer for the *Can't bind to '' since it isn't a known property of ''* query. This comment might help a bit...

Comment: @netzaffin This is a useful answer but I've ran into the can't bind error many many times and this is the first time this was the actual problem/solution.

Comment: How do I bind a callback function to data-* attributes too?

Comment: @Malik What callback function? Attribute values can only be strings and you can't express a function reference as string. This has nothing to do with Angular, that's a pure DOM thing.

Answer (score 59):

About access

```
<ol class="viewer-nav">
    <li *ngFor="let section of sections" 
        [attr.data-sectionvalue]="section.value"
        (click)="get_data($event)">
        {{ section.text }}
    </li>  
</ol>
```

And

```
get_data(event) {
   console.log(event.target.dataset.sectionvalue)
}
```