# Custom attribute gives parsing error when using with an angular 2.0.0-beta.0

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to use custom attribute with angular2 as following

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="{{inst.title}}" data-loc="{{inst.actionval}}">
```

which gives me following error

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'loc' since it isn't a known native property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 data attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Angular by default uses property binding but `a` doesn't have a property data-loc. To tell Angular explicitly to use attribute binding, use instead:
try this one may work for you.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="{{inst.title}}" [attr.data-loc]="inst.actionval">
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="{{inst.title}}" attr.data-loc="{{inst.actionval}}">
```

Comment: Since the original user who asked did not respond, I would like to say that with the released version of angular 2 the first suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: ohh okay so should i remove the second opption ?

Comment: No, that one works also. My bad, when I tried it I didn't remove the square brackets. Both options are viable.

Comment: Tks @PardeepJain