# How to use the *ngFor=let value as html property value in angular 2

Tags: angular, property-binding

Im trying to use the value of `{{facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16}}` as property value of `data-clipboard-text = facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16`

This is a fragment of my code

```
<tr *ngFor="let facturaCE of facturasClientesExistentes">
<td>{{facturaCE.cantidad}} --> {{facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16}}</td>
<td>{{facturaCE.cliente}}</td>
<td>{{facturaCE.correo}}</td>
<td>{{facturaCE.fecha}}</td>
<td>{{facturaCE.sucursal}}</td>
<td>
<button class="btn button" data-clipboard-text="I WANT TO USE HERE">Cantidad
</button>
<button (click)="facturaTerminada('clienteExistente', facturaCE)" class="button alert">Marcar como realizada
</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using *Clipboard.js* thats why have the property *data-clipboard-text* and it's working if I use some sample text.

Already try to use `data-clipboard-text="{{facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16}}"`

Comment: I dont understand. `data-clipboard-text = "facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16"` is not working?

Comment: @suraj thanks for answer, but if just put the text `data-clipboard-text = "facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16"` the value is the same text. And

if i surround with `{{ facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16 }}` I got an the next error

_Can't bind to 'clipboard-text' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("          <td>{{facturaCE.sucursal}}</td>_

Comment: you need to user attribute binding..have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34542844/1160236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`[attr.data-clipboard-text]=" facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16"`

Or

`attr.data-clipboard-text="{{facturaCE.cantidad / 1.16}}"`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should be using as below

```
<button class="btn button" attr.data-clipboard-text="{{facturaCE.cantidad/1.6}}">
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RYnIhPvsdy3Mnm3leWaU?p=preview)**