# How to bind to a data attribute using Angular 2+?

Tags: css, binding, angular2-template

I am using a data table created mostly with css that I found online. In one of the columns there is a css data attribute "data-title" which is assigned a string.

```
<td data-title="someString">
```

When I enter a string, the styling inside the column works as expected. When I try to bind to an objects string, the binding doesn't work like I would expect. I tried

```
<td data-title="object.someString">
```

which just displays literal 'object.someString' and I tried

```
<td data-title="{{object.someString}}">
```

which displays nothing (blank). Any idea why my binding isn't working here?

CSS:

```
.responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  float: left;
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #565248;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
    content: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS. Is it using the `td::before { content: attr('data-title'); }` property and function?

Comment: @Dai edited with relevant CSS

Comment: Please undo your edit that *incorrectly* refers to the attributes as "CSS selector attributes". The `data-` attributes are not "CSS selector attributes". CSS selectors can use any element attribute.

Comment: Got it. Changed to data attribute

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Angular 2 doesn't bind to `data-` attributes using the simpler `{{ }}` syntax because it tries to map them to DOM properties, and there isn't a DOM property for `data-title` (and it seems Angular2 isn't smart enough to use `dataset` yet - unless I'm missing something).

So to bind to `data-` attributes you need to use the `attr.data-title={{}}` or `[attr.data-...]=""` syntax. See this QA: [Angular 2 data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes)

```
<td [attr.data-title]="object.someString">
```

Or:

```
<td attr.data-title="{{object.someString}}">
```

Comment: It is completely valid for me !
Thanks!

Comment: Can i also bind a function to data-* attribute? I've tried but it just doesn't work.