# Best way to bind html tag with object

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

Let's say I have following img tag:

```
<img *ngFor="let icon of icons" [src]="item.imageSrc">
```

Where icons is array of Icon objects:

```
export class Icon {
    name;
    imageSrc;
    description;
}
```

I need to handle event on this img tag element and I would like to see in the event also the object icon. I have some ideas - for example just creating Component, or filtering list by name which is unique with changing a little bit html code to:

```
<img *ngFor="let item of icons" [src]="item.imageSrc" [name]="item.name" >
```

However I feel it's not proper way for this issue. Can i give a property to img tag that will store this object?

Comment: I think that's what the `data-` attributes were created for, however I don't really know how to feel about storing data in the view layer. You can read about `data` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: I have found the topic which recommends using attr instead of data-* for Angular projects. [Topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes)
However this topic does not solve my problem. It works only for Strings, not for whole objects - however I try to modify it.

Comment: I'd just use the filter approach you mentioned to be honest.