# Error While Passing Data to Custom Attribute in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

Hi I Want to add JSON data to the Custom HTML Attribute. I Tried Below Format but it Throws Error Element not a Attribute Property of LI.

Here is the screenshot i want to pass data.

http://prntscr.com/hwt4rf

please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: please show your code in this question. do not screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li [attr.data-thumb]="link + imtest.file">
```

Next time please paste code.

Comment: it is not linked with any attribute

Comment: it is an external attribute not defined in application it is custom attribute

Comment: That's why you need to add the `attr.` part

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<li [attr.data-thumb]="link+imtest.file">
    <img [src]="link+imtest.file" class="testing">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute binding syntax instead

```
[attr.data-thumb]
```