# Pass data to bootstrap modal in angular 6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular6

I am trying to add modal in my project so that if i click on the one link the modal should show name of that particular link.

But it giving me an Error

please check below link

[link for modal](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5epsw)

Comment: It is better to use angular version of bootstrap to do this. e.g. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @MartinAdámek , but want to try with bootstrap 4 . I want to know why those errors are coming

Comment: It is still bootstrap 4, just different implementation, that plays nice with angular change detection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is better to use angular version of bootstrap to do this, that plays nice with angular change detection.

e.g. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Then you will have one component representing your modal, and to pass data to it, just declare public property and do this:

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(YourModalComponent);
(modalRef.componentInstance as YourModalComponent).yourProperty = yourValue;
```

Btw to fix the error you are talking about, you could use `attr` property binding, like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#' + products.name">
```

It will fix the error, but the modal is still not working, looks like you are also missing CSS there.

Answer (score 2):

Got answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes)

Update The code in

[stackblitz line](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5epsw)

we should use

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                          [attr.data-target]="'#'+products.name">
      {{products.name}}
 </button>
```

Comment: Well, i already gave you the same solution in my answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

in this example, i show how to pass Id to bootstrap modal because not a good idea to identify the model by another field than Id

```
<button  class="btn btn-primary" 
            data-toggle="modal" 
            [attr.data-target]="'#Model'+category.idCategory">Open Model
</button>

<div class="modal fade in" 
     id="Model{{category.idCategory}}"
     tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
     aria-hidden="true">......
</div>
```