# How to show separate data for each bootstrap modal using angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looping through images which oncliking a modal pops up with its info. The problem is that all the modals from all images appear to have the same , that of the first image

Here's what i've done.

```
data:any;
```

Html

```
<div  *ngFor =" let mydata of data">
   <img [src]="mydata.image" >
    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">View info </a>
      <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<p>{{mydata.info}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I Got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839198/pass-data-to-bootstrap-modal-in-angular-6)

Answer (score 0):

This realization is very inefficient. But if forgot about that. You have a problem because of using the same `id` for every modal.

```
<div *ngFor ="let mydata of data; let i = index">
   <img [src]="mydata.image" >
    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#exampleModal' + i">View info </a>
      <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " [attr.id]="'exampleModal' + i" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<p>{{mydata.info}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

This will resolve the issue for one instance of the parent component (if you want to use this component multiple times, this implementation will not be working properly).

Comment: I'm getting an error " Can't bind to 'data.target' since it isn't a known property of 'a'." @izmaylovdev

Comment: @Patiee updated my answer