# Binding angular component variable to CSS data attributes

Tags: angular

I'm getting started with Angular from React and I'm trying to make use of CSS attributes with dynamic data from the Angular Component.

Here's what I've tried so far, and I'm a bit confused.

```
<div id="application-menu" data-open="{{ menu }}">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

In my page I am declaring the menu to be "open"

```
export class AuthPage {
  menu = "true";
}
```

In SCSS I am using the `[attribute]` feature to handle conditional rendering.

```
#application-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: transparent;

    .background {
        position: absolute;
        left: -100px;
        top: -100px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    &[data-open="true"] {
        pointer-events: all;
        .background {
        background-color: green;
        border-radius: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass the value of `menu` from the Angular component to the `data-open` property of the div to be used in SCSS for conditional rendering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Since `data-open` is an attribute, not a property, of the `div` element, you should use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding):

```
<div id="application-menu" [attr.data-open]="menu">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6nenxf) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr` for binding to data attributes:

```
<div id="application-menu" [attr.data-open]="menu">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```