# Can't bind variable to string

Tags: angular7, variable-binding

I am new to angular and I am currently using Angular 7. I can't add the variable to data-link property.

In my `ts` file I have a variable :

```
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit {
     var = "#item1";
}
```

And in HTML I have:

```
<li class="item group1" data-link="{{var}}">
        text
</li>
```

But this doesn't work, and shows the following error:

> Can't bind to 'link' since it isn't a known property of...

Comment: Use attribute binding syntax. See: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

The `var` is reserved word in javascript - typescript so you can't use it like this.

The `var` statement declares a variable.

You can find all reserved words here [enter link description here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2536)

This is how your code will work:

TS

```
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit {
     element = "#item1"; // Change var to anything not reserved
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="item group1" data-link="{{element}}">
        text
</li>
```

Comment: Thank  you , Var is just an example , even when i try element not worknig 


i just find the correct answer , we should but attar befor the unknown property to be ((  attr.data-link ))  

that solve the problem in case anyone go throw it ..