# Custom html using angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I want to use this html an loop for angular

```
<div >
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
<option data-tokens="ketchup mustard1">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
<option data-tokens="mustard2">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
<option data-tokens="frosting3">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
</div>
```

When use

```
<select class="/*form-control*/ selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="{{'idCoin'+i}}" [(value)]="customer.idCoin" required>
<option *ngFor="let item of idCoinlist" [value]="item.id" data-tokens="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Show error:
Can't bind to 'tokens' since it isn't a known property of 'option'.ng

HOw i can use loop with custom html? Thanks!

Comment: Use attribute binding syntax. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34542844/9471852)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am placing the `*ngFor` loop in ng-container. ng-container does not get rendered, rather the contents of it will be.

You were missing `i`, I am guessing it should come from loop index, so I added that as index.

`customer.idCoin` can't be referenced. I am guessing prop `customer` is on `item`? Added this as well. But check this part over yourself. You haven't provided what the data structure is like.

`{{item.id}}` for the tokens, does not need to be enclosed in brackets. However `{{item.name}}` does need to be. When you want to print something in html literal (the part which user can see) you wrap it in `{{}}` to bind it. To use it as a value in the html tag - you don't wrap it.

```html
<select class="/*form-control*/ selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="{{'idCoin'+i}}"
          [(value)]="customer.idCoin" required>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of idCoinlist; index as i">
            <option [value]="item.id" [attr.data-tokens]="item.id">{{item.name}}
            </option>
          </ng-container>
        </select>
```

Comment: Thanks! With some fixes it works!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed answer:

```
<select class="/*form-control*/ selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="{{'idCoin'+i}}"
          [(value)]="customer.idCoin" required>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of idCoinlist; index as i">
            <option [value]="item.id" [attr.data-tokens]="item.id">{{item.name}}
            </option>
          </ng-container>
        </select>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).