# How can I change the class in ts code when the style is in the css library

Tags: css, angular, typescript

In coustume-webkit.css I have this code:

```
.tabella .pagination > li:last-child > a:before, .tabella .pagination > li:last-child > span:before {
    padding-right: 5px;
    content: "avanti";
    width: 60px;
}
```

in html code I used `pagination` class like this:

```
      <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="paginate_button previous" [ngClass]="{'disabled': pageActive === 1}"
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button" [ngClass]="{'active': page===pageActive}"
                *ngFor="let page of _totalPageSlice">               
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button next" id="{{id}}_{{id}}_next"
                [ngClass]="{'disabled': pageActive === _totalPage}" label="_next">
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I want to manage the `content: "avanti";` in this class from ts code. Can you give me an idea how to access the `content: "avanti";` from ts code?

Comment: You could use CSS Variables and change them inside your javascript/typescript Code: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables_javascript.asp

Comment: for your information I tried to list all stylesheets loaded on the page, intercepting that specific rule and changing the content value. It doesn't change. While background for example does. So I guess there are restrictions and it could be a dead end for using that strategy. The custom property suggested above could be a good compromise so that it's written once and used many times and easy to change. But it depends on your exact scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of `::before` and `::after` elements can be externally managed with data attributes. Add a data attribute to the targeted HTML tag and use the CSS `attr()` function to read the content from the tag.

adjusted CSS code:

```
.tabella .pagination > li:last-child > a:before, .tabella .pagination > li:last-child > span:before {
    padding-right: 5px;
    content: attr(data-name);
    width: 60px;
}
```

adjusted HTML code

```
<ul class="pagination">
            <li class="paginate_button previous" [ngClass]="{'disabled': pageActive === 1}"
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button" [ngClass]="{'active': page===pageActive}"
                *ngFor="let page of _totalPageSlice">               
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button next" id="{{id}}_{{id}}_next"
                [ngClass]="{'disabled': pageActive === _totalPage}" label="_next">
                <a [attr.data-name]="dataValue">Some link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Now you can have a `dataValue`-property in your angular component that can handle the content:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  public dataValue = "avanti";
}
```

Checkout

- [How can I write data attributes using Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/how-can-i-write-data-attributes-using-angular)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

for more information

Comment: Can you write an example please?

Comment: I updated using your example

Comment: If you can not edit the CSS code, because it's from some external library, then you have to use something with a higher specificity. This should work:

.tabella .pagination > li:last-child > a:before[data-name], .tabella .pagination > li:last-child > span:before[data-name] {
    content: attr(data-name);
}