# Is it possible to bind an Angular property value into the value of an HTML data attribute?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to bind an Angular property value to a data attribute on a template element?

```html
<h1 data-name="{{name}}">Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3pnbvw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

When we run that, it produces this error:

```
Error in src/main.ts (11:9)
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'h1'.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write data attributes using Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/how-can-i-write-data-attributes-using-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
<h1 [attr.data-name]="name">Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
```

Based on [How can I write data attributes using Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/how-can-i-write-data-attributes-using-angular)